# Flutter sound on ios not working with soundpool package

Tags: ios, flutter

I am using [soundpool](https://pub.dev/packages/soundpool) to play small mp3 sounds in my app. On android everything works fine. But on ios it just won't work. I don't get any error at all, but it just does not play the sound. Neither in the simulator nor on my real device.

This is my code:

```
_successSoundId = await rootBundle.load("assets/sounds/success.mp3").then((ByteData soundData) {
  return pool.load(soundData);
});
await pool.play(_successSoundId)
```

pubspec:

```
dependencies:
    soundpool: ^2.3.0

assets:
    - assets/sounds/
```

Do I need some permissions or something? What am I missing here.

Comment: are you sure that `_successSoundId` is >= 0?

Comment: tried on a real device?

Comment: @pskink actually it is zero

Comment: @HasilT I wrote in my question, that I tried it on a real device

Comment: zero is ok, and what ID does `play` method returns in the `Future`?

Comment: @pskink the id is zero too

Comment: and this time zero is bad ;-( unfortunately they don't say much what it really means here https://pub.dev/documentation/soundpool/latest/soundpool/Soundpool/play.html

Comment: btw are you sure that your iphone can handle that MP3? I know it may sound stupid but ...

Comment: @pskink actually I have no clue about what sounds an iphone can play. I just assumed it should work. At least when I send it via telegram, I can play it. But idk if telegram converts it.

Comment: @pskink well it is an iphone after all. I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: @pskink I tried with an aac file. But same issue.

Comment: tried to run https://github.com/ukasz123/soundpool/tree/master/soundpool/example? all those sources you have in the soundpool installation folder

Comment: I've build the example repo now. And there I get >0 values when playing sounds, but it still won't work. I can't hear a thing. I tried it in simulator and on my iphone.

Comment: so it seems you have to talk to package author .... ;-(